# Pass Google Sheet ID or URL to Apps Script Web App

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I have developed an Apps Script project for my school district. Basically it generates writing portfolios for every student in the district, precreates their documents, and dumps all that info into a generated Google Sheet. From that Google Sheet a teacher can launch a web app that contains a rubric in a web form format along with a view of the document so they can quickly and easily grade everything and send those grades to the students.  Honestly everything works fine. It is just that right now when I run the script and generate all of these documents I have to manually go in to each Google Sheet and copy and paste the ID so that the web app can find all the students and the links to their documents since you obviously cannot use getActiveSpreadsheet() in a Web App. I'd like to be able to turn this into an add on or at least save myself some time as other districts are starting to take interest in it and my teachers are wanting it tweaked and implemented for other uses in their classrooms.

So does anyone have any idea of how I could get that Google Sheet ID from the Google Sheet to the web app? Currently I create a menu onOpen, they click to launch the grading app which opens a dialog, and then they click a link to the grading app.  I tried using jquery to dynamically create that link and put the ID in a URL but the link gets scrambled. I'm guessing something to do with Apps scripts restrictions.

All the solutions I have seen involve ScriptProperties or ScriptDB which I believe has been taken away.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to a webApp. The doGet(event) trigger saves it in the event object. For example you can build the URL:
`https://script.google.com/.........../exec?scriptId=...`

In your webApp:

```
function doGet(e){
  var scriptId = e.parameter.scriptId;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

You say it is getting "scrambled". I would look to your code for that error. If you post some code showing how you're building the URL I'm sure we can figure it out.

Comment: By scrambled I mean that it will start with n1...script.googleuser.content or something like that. I realized that basically what it meant was that I had written my javascript or Jquery wrong so the URL wasn't properly formed. So it was on my end not there's.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response as this project has been crazy. Plus I like to chew on things before I just throw a response back. I appreciate your answer but I am needing the ID of the Google Sheet you launch the web app from. So could I use var scriptId = e.parameter.sheetId ? Because I want that sheet ID as a parameter in the web app URL so I think acess it in openById();